# VBA function returning nothing when opening an external file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and have been having a lot of difficulty with reading external files. Right now, I'm simply trying to make a function that will copy a table from an external sheet into the add-in file for quick use. Every time I run it, however, it says that the sheet wasn't found despite me checking very thoroughly that I've spelt everything correctly and the file exists.

```
Option Explicit

Function CopySheetFromExternalFile(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim selectedFilePath As String
    Dim externalWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim externalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copiedSheet As Worksheet

    ' Create a file dialog object
    Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    ' Configure the file dialog
    With fileDialog
        .Title = "Select Workbook"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    ' Show the file dialog and get the selected file path
    If fileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        selectedFilePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        ' User canceled the file dialog
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Open the selected external workbook
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application
    excelApp.Visible = False
    Set externalWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(selectedFilePath)

    ' Check if the sheet exists in the external workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set externalSheet = excelApp.externalWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If externalSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error: Sheet '" & sheetName & "' not found in the selected workbook.", vbExclamation
        externalWorkbook.Close False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Copy the sheet into ThisWorkbook
    externalSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    ' Optionally, you can rename the newly copied sheet
    Set copiedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    copiedSheet.Name = sheetName & "_Copy" ' Change the name as needed

    ' Close the external workbook without saving changes
    externalWorkbook.Close False

    CopySheetFromExternalFile = True
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    If Not externalWorkbook Is Nothing Then externalWorkbook.Close False
    CopySheetFromExternalFile = False
End Function
```

I've tried rewriting this code multiple different ways but it always fails to open the file. What's really strange is I have another function I made which uses this exact same method to read files and that works perfectly.

Comment: `Set externalSheet = excelApp.externalWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)` ----> `Set externalSheet = externalWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)`

Comment: Was about to leave the same comment :)  The reason this error wasn't noticeable is that it is sandwiched between `On Error Resume Next` / `On Error Goto 0`.  If you step through your code with the debugger and after the problematic line enter `?err.description` in the Immediate window, you'll see the underlying error is "Object doesn't support this property or method".  As in: `excelApp` doesn't have a property named `externalWorkbook`.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you guys very much. I added excelApp before externalWorkbook because if I didn't it would just give me a value error, but the real problem is with the line where I copy the sheet into ThisWorkbook. Any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: "Value error" - are you trying to use this formula as a UDF called from a worksheet cell? "The real problem is" - please provide more detail.

Comment: Yes I'm using it as a UDF. After adding ?err.description underneath of the line externalSheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) I get the error "Method not valid without suitable object"

Comment: Why are you using this as a UDF? That's a fraught endeavor. UDFs are very restricted in what they can do. UDFs are not meant to open workbooks or copy sheets or similar. They are only meant to return a value to the calling cell.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can copy a worksheet from another application instance.

Comment: Ultimately I wanted to use this for another function once I got it working. The idea was that users could add multiple tables from different sheets and choose between them in Excel for a formula to use. If not a UDF, what would recommend I do?

Comment: Use a `Sub`routine. I don't see the need for a new excel instance either.